# SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0 - JSON Rest API

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm working with a JSON rest API that has the following response:

```
// response
[
  {
    id: 1,
    userId: 1,
    start: "2018-01-01 10:15",
    finish: "2018-01-01 12:20",
    breakLength: 30
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    userId: 1,
    start: "2018-01-02 10:15",
    finish: "2018-01-02 18:20",
    breakLength: 45
  }
];
```

See below for code. Like my other functions, I am requesting a GET using `fetch()`. However, sometimes this function when called requests and responds with a `200`, and sometimes it responds with a `400 bad request`(*Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0*) It seems very random when it happens. My server which the JSON Rest API is on is `localhost:3000` and my application is on `localhost:3001`. I have used this same method for other JSON requests and they work perfectly. I am not sure why this one is having trouble? Thanks for your help!

**Update**: It seems as though the last `Promise.all`, `setState` is not being executed. The program is crashing on line `.then(response => response.json())` in `promise3`.

**Updated Code**:

```
    getShifts = (sessionId) => {
        return fetch("http://localhost:3000/shifts", {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": sessionId
          }
        });
      };


callbackSessionId = (sessionId) => {
    let promise1 = this.fetchUserAttributes(sessionId)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => this.setState({
            userAttributes: json
        }));
    Promise.all([promise1]).then(() => {
        let promise2 = this.getOrganisations(sessionId)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => this.setState({
                organisations: json
            }));
        let promise3 = this.getShifts(sessionId)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => this.setState({
                shifts: json
            }));
        // this.setState({
        //     sessionId: sessionId
        // });
        Promise.all([promise2, promise3]).then(() => {
            this.setState({
                sessionId: sessionId
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: You should NOT edit your question and remove the initial question. Leave the original question as-is and rather add your own answer below. Otherwise users will be very confused when they later discover the question (like me) they won't know what the original issue was, and if it even relates to them.

Comment: Rolled the last edit back in order to bring back the question, precisely for the reason @Andre mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code: you should always return your promises, headers property names should be quoted and React setState is an asynchronous method.

Please, try to update it like below to see if it works, I'll edit expanding on the details if it does.

```
getShifts = (sessionId) => {
    return fetch("http://localhost:3000/shifts", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": sessionId
        }
    });
};

fetchData = (sessionId) => {
    let promise3 = this.getShifts(this.state.sessionId)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => this.setState({shifts: json}, this.forceUpdate));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed it and same problem occurs. I have done this for my other fetches and these headers worked fine. Like I said, I am consuming an existing JSON REST API, not sure if this is of use?

Comment: are you also passing Authorization headers on these other fetches?

Comment: Anyway, the Content-Type headers being set on your equest would only make sense when sending content TO the API, not when receiving content FROM the API.

Comment: I'll update my answer with what I think is the right code, but it hard for me to test it right now.

Comment: Still getting the same error. I see you aren't doing `Promise.all`? I have updated my code fully. Please see what I currently have. My `getOrganisations` and `fetchUserAttributes` work fine, only `getShifts` procs an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is actually invalid. All keys need to be string literals, so your correct JSON would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "start": "2018-01-01 10:15",
    "finish": "2018-01-01 12:20",
    "breakLength": 30
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "userId": 1,
    "start": "2018-01-02 10:15",
    "finish": "2018-01-02 18:20",
    "breakLength": 45
  }
]
```

Comment: I get what you are trying to do, and I see your point. I have done similar to another GET request with the same structure and it has worked.